# Apex heap size too large error

Tags: apex, class, case, heap

Is there any way to make this apex class more efficient? Currently, whenever a case with many case comments is escalated in our system, an error occurs stating the Apex heap size is too large. Any ideas or recommendations?

Here is the class:

```
  public class EscalateCaseController{  
    public Case ccCase;  
    public String internalComment;  

    public EscalateCaseController(){
        try{
        ccCase = new Case();
        //Query the field values of the original case to be escalated
        ccCase = [SELECT Id,
                         AccountId,
                         ContactId,
                         Asset__c,
                         Component__c,
                         Subject,
                         Description,
                         Steps_to_Reproduce__c,
                         //Browser__c,
                         //Internal_Category__c,
                         Priority,
                         Corrected_Version__c,
                         Version__c
                  FROM Case
                  WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') LIMIT 1];
                  internalComment = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Comment');
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'There was an error fetching the Case record details. Please contact your administrator.'));
        }
    }


    public PageReference EscalateToEngineering(){
        try{
            //Get recordTypeId necessary for escalated case
            Id rtId = SystemIds__c.getInstance().RecordTypeId_Case_Engineering__c;
            //Get Engineering Queue Id
            Id engineeringId = [SELECT Id, Name, Type
                                From Group
                                WHERE Type = 'Queue'
                                    AND Name = 'Engineering' LIMIT 1].Id;
            //Create Escalated Case based from ccCase (Original Case)
            Case newCase = new Case(Asset__c = ccCase.Asset__c,
                                    recordTypeId = rtId, //Engineering Case record type
                                    ownerId = engineeringId, //Set Engineering queue as the case Owner
                                    Escalation_Comments__c = internalComment,
                                    Component__c = ccCase.Component__c,
                                    Subject = ccCase.Subject,
                                    //Description = ccCase.Description,
                                    //Steps_to_Reproduce__c = ccCase.Steps_to_Reproduce__c, --
                                    Priority = ccCase.Priority,
                                    //Browser__c = ccCase.Browser__c,
                                    Hide_Case_in_Portal__c = true,
                                    //Internal_Category__c = ccCase.Internal_Category__c,
                                    AccountId = ccCase.AccountId,
                                    ContactId = ccCase.ContactId,
                                    Support_Case_Version__c = ccCase.Version__c,
                                    Corrected_Version__c = ccCase.Corrected_Version__c);
            insert newCase;
            //Query attachments of support case
            List<Attachment> supportAttachmentsList = [SELECT Id, ParentId, Body, Name FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :ccCase.Id];
            List<Attachment> escalateAttachmentsList = supportAttachmentsList.deepClone(false, true, true);
            for(Attachment loopAttachments : escalateAttachmentsList){
                loopAttachments.parentId = newCase.Id;
            }
            insert escalateAttachmentsList;
            //Update original Case
            ccCase.Escalation_to_Dev__c = true;
            ccCase.Dev_No__c = newCase.CaseNumber;
            ccCase.Status = 'Pending Development';
            ccCase.parentId = newCase.Id;//Linked Case
            update ccCase;
            //Update escalation case
            //newCase.Description = ccCase.Description;
            update newCase;
            //Redirect to edit page of the Escalated Case
            return new PageReference('/' + newCase.Id + '/e?retURL=/' + newCase.Id);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A Quick google search will be able to help you, this is from a cursory search http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/08/16/managing-the-heap-in-salesforce-com/

Answer (score 2):

The cause of your big heap size is the fact that you are cloning the attachments. I am guessing that you have several attachments which are very big in size. I am assuming that you will not be able to control this, since a case might have many attachments and each attachment can have up to 25 MB. Your max heap size is 6MB or 12MB for asynchronous.

Try declaring supportAttachmentsList and escalateAttachmentsList as "transient". If that doesn't help, you might have to limit the size that is allowed for Case attachments, or else will have to forget about cloning the attachments altogether.

You could also probably get fancy with future calls, by cloning each attachment in a future call but that will only help you increase the size of the attachments allowed to 12 MB. It will also introduce new limitations, since there is a limit as to how many future calls can be made in a transaction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. But yes there is a particular case that is causing the issue and it happens to have a lot of attachments and case comments. I will probably declare those values as transient and manually escalate the case if the heap is still large.